# How to select columns from a relation

Tags: strapi, bookshelf.js

so I'm using Strapi and Bookshelf. The `.query()` is a normal bookshelf query.

```
const result = await strapi.query('friendship').model
    .query({
        where: { user1: 1 },
        orWhere: { user2: 1 }
    })
    .fetchAll()
```

Now, `user1,2` are 1-to-1 relations to `user` and I'd like to select e.g. `id` and `username`. If I output result, everythings there. How can I tell it to just select those columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following (specifying columns in fetchAll()) works for me however there's no relations in my case:

```
const result = await strapi.query('friendship').model
  .query({
    where: { user1: 1 },
    orWhere: { user2: 1 }
  })
  .fetchAll({columns:["id", "username"]})
```

You can refer to the options description from [Bookshelf.js](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-instance-fetch).